# Best practices for creating a huge SQL table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, coding-style, large-data

I want to create a table about "users" for each of the 50 states. Each state has about 2GB worth of data. Which option sounds better?

1. Create one table called "users" that will be 100GB large OR
2. Create 50 separate tables called "users_{state}", each which will be 2GB large

I'm looking at two things: performance, and style (best practices)

I'm also running RDS on AWS, and I have enough storage space. Any thoughts?

EDIT: From the looks of it, I will not need info from multiples states at the same time (i.e. won't need to frequently join tables if I go with Option 2). Here is a common use case: The front-end passes a state id to the back-end, and based on that id, I need to query data from the db regarding the specified state, and return data back to front-end.

Comment: It depends a lot on how you are going to access the data, The question is too broad without more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are the 50 states truly independent in your business logic? Meaning your queries would only need to run over one given state most of the time? If so, splitting by state is probably a good choice. In this case you would only need joining in relatively rarer queries like reporting queries and such.

**EDIT:** Based on your recent edit, this first option is the route I would recommend. You will get better performance from the table partitioning when no joining is required, and there are multiple other benefits to having the smaller partitioned tables like this.

- If your queries would commonly require joining across a majority of the states, then you should definitely not partition like this. You'd be better off with one large table and just build the appropriate indices needed for performance. Most modern enterprise DB solutions are capable of handling the marginal performance impact going from 2GB to 100GB just fine (with proper indexing).
- But if your queries on average would need to join results from only a handful of states (say no more than 5-10 or so), the optimal solution is a more complex gray area. You will likely be able to extract better performance from the partitioned tables with joining, but it may make the code and/or queries (and all coming maintenance) noticeably more complex.

Note that my answer assumes the more common access frequency breakdowns: high reads, moderate updates, low creates/deletes. Also, if performance on big data is your primary concern, you may want to check out NoSQL (for example, Amazon AWS DynamoDB), but this would be an invasive and fundamental departure from the relational system. But the NoSQL performance benefits can be absolutely dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more of your model, it will be difficult for anyone to make judgement calls about performance, etc. However, from a data modelling point of view, when thinking about a normalized model I would expect to see a User table with a column (or columns, in the case of a compound key) which hold the foreign key to a State table. If a User could be associated with more than one state, I would expect another table (UserState) to be created instead, and this would hold the foreign keys to both User and State, with any other information about that relationship (for instance, start and end dates for time slicing, showing the timespan during which the User and the State were associated).

Rather than splitting the data into separate tables, if you find that you have performance issues you could use partitioning to split the User data by state while leaving it within a single table. I don't use MySQL, but a quick Google turned up plenty of reference information on how to implement partitioning within MySQL.

Until you try building and running this, I don't think you know whether you have a performance problem or not. If you do, following the above design you can apply partitioning after the fact and not need to change your front-end queries. Also, this solution won't be problematic if it turns out you *do* need information for multiple states at the same time, and won't cause you anywhere near as much grief if you need to look at User by some aspect other than State.